# missing play sources when using sbt gen-idea

Tags: scala, playframework, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm using the Play framework on a project and use IntelliJ as my IDE of choice.

The problem I'm having is that IntelliJ doesn't have access to the play sources jar, meaning I can't step into play code etc.

When I use `> sbt gen-idea` the scalatra sources are attached to the project in IntelliJ but for some reason the play sources are not attached.

Is there a special command that needs ran? I am currently using sbt 0.11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer it seems is to use the `withSources` command in sbt.

```
sbt idea withSources
```

this is similar to the eclipse plugins

```
sbt eclipsify withSources=true
```

Comment: Works great, but with more recent sbt's it is "sbt idea with-source=true"

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
sbt gen-idea sbt-classifiers
```

If the source is added by the build (plugins) rather than in your build file, then it won't be added to the IDEA configuration by default.

There was a [recent bug in sbt](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/issues/304) whereby you had to have the source for any plugins you were using installed in your local repo before this command would work properly. I think I checked out `sbt-idea` from github and `sbt install`ed it to get round this.

The plugin author for sbt-idea explains it in [this comment](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/issues/119#issuecomment-3597764). The bug has been fixed in later versions of sbt.

Comment: yeah, no luck. I ended up packaging the sources myself from the source code and attaching it manually.

Comment: `sbt gen-idea sbt-classifiers` worked OK for me. See the update to my answer about a similar issue I had when using 0.11.2.

Comment: Confirmed on sbt 0.13 with sbt-idea 1.5.1 and Play 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

sbt update-classifiers
   sbt update-sbt-classifiers
   sbt gen-idea sbt-classifiers

Create a command alias in Build.scala to chain all those commands.

sbt generate-project

http://www.plotprojects.com/create-an-intellij-idea-project-with-library-sources-attached/